# Que signifie « voilà qui ne gêne pas les procureurs » ?

Tags: sens, connotation

Dans le texte *Le monolinguisme de l'autre* par Derrida, j'ai trouvé cette phrase:

> Que cette scène soit vieille comme le monde, en tout cas comme la
>   philosophie, voilà qui ne gêne pas les procureurs

Je ne comprends pas la dernière proposition. C'est quoi la signification du mot « voilà » ? Et c'est quoi la connotation du mot « procureur » dans la contexte d'une discussion de philosophie ?

Comment: [« Voilà qui »](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=voil%C3%A0+qui)

Answer (score 3):

> REM<sup>1</sup>. ***Voilà*** classé parmi les prépositions a en effet une valeur de verbe (on peut la remplacer par "c'est là, ce sont là").
>   Présente un personne ou une chose, plus particulièrement lorsqu'elle est relativement éloignée.

Dans *[le texte original, page 18](http://entre-l%C3%A0.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Derrida-Le-monolinguisme-de-lautre1.pdf)*, l'auteur expose les affrontements entre philosophes et s'intéresse aux arguments présentés.
*Voilà* renvoie à ce qui a été précédemment exposé.

Certains endossent le *rôle de procureur* (d'une thèse philosophique), pour porter l'accusation sur l'adversaire (un philosophe, accusé de ne rien comprendre, qu'il faut dénigrer, dont les arguments sont ineptes ou dangereux...),
... comme un *procureur de la République* peut le faire sur un accusé durant un procès au palais de justice !

---

*<sup>1 Référence extraite du petit Robert</sup>*

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse, mais je ne comprends toujours pas ce que _voilà_ ajoute à la phrase. Est-ce que le sens de la phrase serait la même si on le remplace par _ce_, ou si on le sublime complètement?

Comment: @JacobRitchie -- Elle aurait un sens affaibli et cela lui retirerait la puissance du plaidoyer, de la mise en valeur du point important qui emporte la démonstration.